# ASP.NET - JSON casting

Tags: asp.net, json

```
var a = JSON.Deserialize<object>(e.ExtraParams["address"]);
```

The JSON

```
[{"id":"","country":"MYcOUNTRY","city":"citycitycity","street":"street","block":"house","building":"building","additionalInfo":"fdsfdsfdsfds","latitude":"32.9206000","longitude":"35.1003000"}]
```

and the class for storing information about address

```
[Serializable]
 class BEAddress{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string Block { get; set; }
     public string Building { get; set; }

     public string Latitude { get; set; }
     public string Longitude { get; set; }
     public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't savvy how to cast the object `a` to `BEAddress`?

**UPDATE**:
The way I seriliaze this data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var <%=ClientID%>_getAddress = function () {
              var jsonObj = [];
              jsonObj.push({
                      Id: <%=AddressIdHdn.ClientID%>.getValue(),
                      Country: <%=cmbCountries.ClientID%> .getRawValue(),
                      City: <%=cmbCities.ClientID%> .getRawValue(),
                      Street: <%=txtStreet.ClientID%> .getValue(),
                      Block: <%=txtBlock.ClientID%> .getValue(),
                      Building: <%=txtBuilding.ClientID%> .getValue(),
                      AdditionalInfo: <%=txtAdditionalInfo.ClientID%> .getValue(),
                      Latitude: <%=txtLatitude.ClientID%> .getValue(),
                      Longitude: <%=txtLongitude.ClientID%> .getValue()
                  });
              return jsonObj;
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you'd need to do the following:

```
BEAddress aVar = JSON.Deserialize<BEAddress>(e.ExtraParams["address"]);
```

At the moment you're turning your JSON into a bog standard 'object' so you'd need to turn the JSON into a specific 'BEAddress' object as per the example above.

Comment: An error occurs "Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'Loginet.Entities.BEAddress'."

Comment: The only thing that sticks out is that your class has it's properties defined with capitals and your JSON is all lowercase. Looking at how I've done this before you'd need thos to match. Just out of interest, is this with Ext.NET?

Comment: Yes, it's ext.net. The error is the same. The result json is  `[{"id":"","country":"Израиль","city":"Гэдера","street":"street","block":"house","building":"building","additionalInfo":"fdsfdsfdsfds","latitude":"32.9206000","longitude":"35.1003000"}]`

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the problem, your JSON would want to be defined like this: [{"Id":"","Country":"Израиль","City":"Гэдера","Street":"street","Block":"house"‌​,"Building":"building","AdditionalInfo":"fdsfdsfdsfds","Latitude":"32.9206000","L​ongitude":"35.1003000"}]

Comment: it was copy/paste problem. My JSON is already defined as you've suggested me. `[{"Id":"","Country":"Бермуды","City":"Гамильтон","Street":"","Block":"","Building":"","AdditionalInfo":"","Latitude":"32.2948160","Longitude":"-64.7813750"}]`

Comment: I've just looked over one of our pages where we've done this precise operation and can't see anything glaringly wrong, have you tried m.edmonsons suggesting of keeping the variable type of 'a' dynamic? I've got examples sitting on front of me of both strongly typed and dynamically typed deserialisation though, so I'm not sure it's that. How have you established that your JSON looks like that? is that taken from the reponse to the Ajax request? could you post the entire response?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try the following:

```
var a = JSON.Deserialize<BEAddress>(e.ExtraParams["address"]);
```

What you're currently doing is deserializing into an generic `object` whereas you need a `BEAddress`.

Also place the `[Serializable]` attribute onto `BEAddress`